# WordPress developer

Tags: php, framework

I would like to know, for being an expert WP developer, it's good to know Zend PHP framework or Symfony? If someone knows Zend, he can learn the WP framework and work with it faster and better or Symfony?

best regards.

Answer (score 3):

Even though technically WordPress is a Content Management System (CMS), I think of it as a framework.  It provides templating, caching, routing, database abstraction, etc.

If you want to be a Wordpress developer you need to know PHP, obviously, but you also need know how WordPress uses PHP and get familiar with the "WordPress Way" of doing things.  You don't need to know Zend or Symfony.

Also, more and more of WordPress is being developed in JavaScript these days, so I would say that learning JS is a crucial part of being a WP dev.

One of the greatest things about WordPress is that it's pretty well documented.  You can view the [official WP docs here](https://codex.wordpress.org/).  This is a great starting point.  Beyond the official docs there is an unlimited wealth of knowledge on the web about WordPress.

Comment: In fact, I have an IT company. I am going to hire some developers. I wanted to know I should hire those people who know Zend or Symfony. Which one is useful for making a website? All of them are advanced on what they know but between Zend and Symfony? most of my clients need WP websites but with so many features and customization

Comment: So hire devs with WP experience...  They are not hard to find

Comment: Just Imagine I have only two options between Zend developer and Symfony, I will be glad if you guide me for this.

Comment: I can't and wouldn't be comfortable giving my opinion on who to hire.  This isn't the right platform for that type of question.

Comment: Dear, I am not asking you to tell me which person should I hire. I asked which type of developer is good for developing WP and also another platform. If I hire the WP developer, he might not be able to make a website from Skratch. I need someone with many abilities to make a website, not only WP but also if someone who can develop WP is better. So I am looking for someone who knows PHP framework but between these two which one is faster to fit with WP framework?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress is a content management system (a publishing tool), Zend and Symfony are frameworks for web applications development. You don't need to know anything about any framework to be an expert WordPress developer.

Comment: In fact, I have an IT company. I am going to hire some developers. I wanted to know I should hire those people who know Zend or Symfony. Which one is useful for making a website? All of them are advanced on what they know but between Zend and Symfony? most of my clients need WP websites but with so many features and customization.